# Need Acer Aspire One D270 video driver for Win8

Tags: windows-8, drivers, acer-aspire

I have installed Windows 8 on my machine and except for the video driver all is working fine.

Where/how can I find a suitable driver for my Acer Aspire One D270, 10.1" netbook?

Comment: Yes. Thanks it works very good on Windows 7, however screen goes black and keeps flickering in Windows 8 till you reboot in safe mode and uninstall the driver. Please advise. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This is the latest driver for the Intel GMA 3600 which is used in your Acer:

**Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator 3600 Series for Windows 7* 32-bit**

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=22633

Answer (score 0):

Today I used external LCD with my netbook. The display changed to 1024x768 as the display was changed to UB4A. All apps of windows 8 were working very well. It remained working till I removed the cable and restarted it. It again became Mobile PC Display. Please is it possible to engage this driver option  permanently. Thanks